# Nested write method doesn't write anything in python

Tags: python

So I'm making a text-only password manager purely in python and I have a function that simply writes to a file. It checks which file it's writing to and writes the data accordingly. The only difference really is the lack of a newline character at the end. Now, whenever the second write method is called in the elif statement, it creates the file, doesn't generate any errors so the program continues, but the file itself is empty.

```
def write_to_file(file, data, function):
    x = input("Y/N: ").lower()
    if x == "y":
        with open(f"{path}\\{file}", mode = "a", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
            if file == "passwords.dat":
                f.write(f"{data}\n")
                print("The password has been saved!")
                retry(function)

            if file == "master_password.dat":
                f.write(data)
                print("The master password has been saved! You will be redirected to the menu shortly.")
                sleep(1)
                main_menu()
```

Comment: Try `flush()`ing your changes.

Comment: Your file won't write without ending on a new line character, but that can be customized: `with open("file.txt", mode='a', newline='') as f:`

Comment: This is what `with` is for.  Just exit the `with` statement, and the file will be flushed and closed.  You shouldn't be using recursion to go back to your main menu anyway.  That's a bad practice.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Is there a better alternative to this?

Comment: No problem, although @TimRoberts is correct, I believe, that `with` is probably the 'Python' way to do this.

Comment: Yes.  This function is called `write_file`.  It should write the file and then RETURN.  Let the caller decide what to do next.  If you return from this function, it will exit the `with` block and the file will be closed properly.

Comment: @Tim Roberts I see, I'll check that out, thanks!